# Make module work in a different theme

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, third-party-module

I've installed an autocomplete search module but it only works with the default Magento theme.

Do I have to call it's layout with a local.xml file on my theme package?

**UPDATE:**
Just to be more clear. I'm using the Porto Theme. This theme have a search module and when I disable it, it suposes to load the original search field but it's not.

I'm almost sure that I need to tell something on my custom local.xml but I realy don't know What.

I already copied all modules, layouts e templates folder to all custom themes folders possiblities (the module is original installed on base theme folder).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your custom theme uses default as a fallback, Magento will load all layouts and templates from the default theme of they are not found in your custom theme.

Check in System > Configuration that your theme uses default as the fallback, and you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you return Robbie. But where I can check the theme "fallback" ?

Comment: General > Design > Themes, set the default value to default and clear your cache

Comment: Here is how my theme configuration looks like: http://imgur.com/dTk2gOB

Comment: What to do in case my theme not using the default theme as fallback ?

Comment: As I said, change the default to default

Comment: If you look in the extension files does it include any files under app>design>frontend>base, if so just copy these over to your custom theme